# Eclipse - custom quick fix - Add some text before and after selection

Tags: eclipse

I could use a dummy guide or directions how to add a custom quick fix or if it is even possible.

Let's say I select a text inside code - "foo foo". Now I want to add something before that text and something after. The content before and after remains the same across many files and it has to be done manually.

Is there a way I could write my own quick fix in eclipse, which would add this text automatically.

Ctrl + 1 -> "Add ... before and ... after" -> And get the desired output?

This seems somewhat useful if not the correct thing, but I can't exactly read out how to accomplish this: [FAQ How do I implement Quick Fixes for my own language?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_implement_Quick_Fixes_for_my_own_language?)

Any easier explanations and guides are appreciated. Or what other ways would I have to accomplish this desired behavior without typing/copying repetitive things

**Edit**: Found this little macro thing which is one way to solve my problem. start with cut, write, paste and end macro. But I'm not sure if this is the best way. [Practically Macro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this solution that allow you to get the result using Eclipse search.

1. CTRL+H to do a search and choose *Files Search*
2. Fill *Containing text* with "foo foo". Tweak other parameters to get the files you want
3. Check *Regular expression*
4. Click on *Replace*
5. Fill *With*: `<prefix>$0<suffix>`. For example if you want to substitute "foo foo" with "this is a foo foo example" write `this is $0 example`
6. Check *Regular expression* (if unchecked).

Done. I think that this solution is quite flexible (as long as you are familiar with regexp to get desidered strings) and easy to apply.